# What is a proper way to specify different remote directories when using DelegatingSessionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I want my DelegatingSessionFactory to search for files in different remote directories on the same server. I try to use RotatingServerAdvice. The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice)  says I need to specify bean IntegrationFlow, which should be defined as

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(sf())
                    .filter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "rotate"))
                    .localDirectory(new File(tmpDir))
                    .localFilenameExpression("#remoteDirectory + T(java.io.File).separator + #root")
                    .remoteDirectory("."),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1).advice(advice())))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("files"))
            .get();
}
```

the problem is that I don't know what to specify in "remoteDirectory" field (they use ".", which I don't know why), also the application won't start unless I use this field. When using RotatingServerAdvice I provide remote directories this way:

```
@Bean
    public RotatingServerAdvice advice() {
        List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String remoteDir: properties.getRemoteDirectory()) {
            keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(SESSION_1_KEY, remoteDir));
        }
        return new RotatingServerAdvice(sftpSessionFactory(), keyDirectories);
    }
```

So, what do I need to do with *.remoteDirectory(".")* to make it work properly?

The full code of my SFTP config is below:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SFTPConfig {

    private static final String SESSION_1_KEY = "SESSION_1";

    private final SFTPProperties properties;
    private final TimeService timeService;

    @Value("${cron.parse}")
    private String cronParse;

    @Bean
    public DelegatingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory defaultSftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setHost(properties.getHost());
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPort(properties.getPort());
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setUser(properties.getUsername());
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setPassword(properties.getPassword());
        defaultSftpSessionFactory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);

        CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> cachingSessionFactory =
                new CachingSessionFactory<>(defaultSftpSessionFactory);
        cachingSessionFactory.setPoolSize(properties.getPoolSize());
        cachingSessionFactory.setSessionWaitTimeout(properties.getTimeout());

        Map<Object, SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();
        sessionMap.put(SESSION_1_KEY, cachingSessionFactory);
        return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(sessionMap, cachingSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel sftpChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler messageHandler(MyService myService, DirectoriesProperties directoriesProperties,
                                         FileService fileService, IHub hub) {
        return new MyMessageHandler(myService, directoriesProperties, fileService, hub);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(MyService myService, DirectoriesProperties directoriesProperties,FileService fileService, IHub hub) {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory())
                                .filter(filter())
                                .localDirectory(new File(properties.getLocalDirectory()))
                                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                                .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                                .localFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>())
                                .remoteDirectory("."),
                        e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron(cronParse).advice(advice())))
                .channel(sftpChannel())
                .handle(messageHandler(myService, directoriesProperties, fileService, hub))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public RotatingServerAdvice advice() {
        List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String remoteDir: properties.getRemoteDirectory()) {
            keyDirectories.add(new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(SESSION_1_KEY, remoteDir));
        }
        return new RotatingServerAdvice(sftpSessionFactory(), keyDirectories);
    }

    private ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry> filter() {
        ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry> filter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        filter.addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter("files_\\d{12}.txt"));
        filter.addFilter(new TimestampPeriodFileListFilter(timeService, properties.getPeriod()));
        return filter;
    }
}
```

I've spent a few days trying to make DelegatingSession work. Before, it used to be just CachingSessionFactory with one remote directory to use. Please, help me to understand what do I have to do with `.remoteDirectory(".")` part. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Artem, thank you for your explanation. I thought my problem was with `.remoteDirectory(".")`, but now I have no suggestion why my integration test fails... Here is the code:

```
public class ParsingTest extends BaseTest {

    @Autowired
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource<File> messageSource;

    @Test
    void shouldSaveAllCalls() {
        String filename = "files_010120230300.txt";
        String resourcePath = "/files/good/" + filename;
        prepareFileInRemoteSftpServer(resourcePath, filename);

        receiveAndHandleFileFromSftp();

    }

    private void prepareFileInRemoteSftpServer(String resourcePath, String remoteFilename) {
        MountableFile mountableFile = MountableFile.forClasspathResource(resourcePath);
        sftpContainer.copyFileToContainer(mountableFile, sftpRemotePath + remoteFilename);
    }

    private void receiveAndHandleFileFromSftp() {
        Message<?> message = messageSource.receive();
        assertThat(message).isNotNull();
        messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
    }

}
```

It fails on the line `assertThat(message).isNotNull();` because message is null.

Would you mind telling me where I am wrong? My only suggestion is about wrong usage of `messageSource.receive();` but I don't know how else I can receive data

Answer (score 0):

That `.remoteDirectory(".")` is just a placeholder. When the polling is in action, that `RotatingServerAdvice` sets a current directory into the `Sftp.inboundAdapter()` overriding your initial placeholder. Not clear what the problem you have. Would you mind to share an error or suspicious behavior?

It is clearly explained in that doc:

> This advice will poll directory `foo` on server `one` until no new files exist then move to directory `bar` and then directory `baz` on server `two`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Artem. I edited the post: added the description of my problem regarding integration test which does not receive data

Comment: I changed defaultPoller bean, and now I set adviceChain directly into it. The behaviour has changed and now I get the following error: `The 'MessageSourceMutator' supports only a 'MessageSource' in the before/after hooks: bean 'sftpChannel'; defined in: 'class path resource [...SFTPConfig.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1a45d5d3'`

Comment: You must not modify a `defaultPoller`. Not sure why would you do that since you already have a proper config: ` e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron(cronParse).advice(advice())))` - exactly on a `Sftp.inboundAdapter()`.

Comment: Your `messageSource.receive();` might not receive the file for several reason: 1. Are you sure that you have configured your session factory for that `/files/good/` dir? 2. Your `integrationFlow` may have already pulled the file before you try to call that `messageSource.receive();`.

Comment: See if `MockIntegration` can help you somehow. I mean you may just mock your `handle()` in the end of the flow and verify it from the unit test: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-mocks

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Artem. Answering your question about why would I change something in defaultPoller bean: Now, thanks to you, I realized that I shouldn't change it. But when I leave `e -> e.poller(Pollers.cron(cronParse).advice(advice())))` I get `BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationFlow' IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'integrationFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.` Is there another way to make a poller with my adviceChain?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your source. You have that `sftpChannel` as a `QueueChannel` and its consumer requires a poller. Yes, you still can configure a `defaultPoller` for this type of endpoints, but it must come without the mentioned advice. Your SFTP message source endpoint must keep its own local poller.